# Suddenly can't connect to external server in Java

Tags: java, http

It's been working perfectly fine all day long, now suddenly I can't connect. I can connect through the browser (and so can you: http://secure.exoterragame.com/noxastra/login.php), but it won't work in my Java application. I get an UnknownHostException.

```
URL register = new URL("http://secure.exoterragame.com/noxastra/login.php" + 
                "?username=" + request.Username + 
                "&password=" + request.Password);

        URLConnection conn = register.openConnection();
```

I am completely stumped. Does anyone know why this would happen?

(Yes, we'll be using https in the final version :P)

Comment: could be a bad suggestion, but once this happened to me and a computer restart made it work again.

Comment: I should probably try that. It always seems to work. :P

Comment: hmm, could you do try with switching off antivirus/firewall, if no other method works?

Comment: try adding the hostname in your hostsfile to see if DNS is the problem. on most recent versions of Windows it's \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, and you add it like so on one line: 205.186.154.148 secure.exoterragame.com

Comment: Never mind, guys. There's more to this, I'll have to figure out what the hell else is going on.

Comment: I bet the browser uses a corporative proxy, and java resolves the name directly. Looks like an isolated DNS failure to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a [packet sniff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) to see what's going on behind the scenes. (I recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for all platforms.)

I had a similar problem in Flash once and was tearing my hair until I realized it was a bug in the VM and it was giving me timeouts without ever sending any packets!

I don't think Java will have such a bug, but the point is, sniffing is sometimes invaluable.

Maybe there's a DNS/hosts-file update which your browser has gotten, but the program not (or the other way around?) Maybe the program's getting stuck on a (local) firewall? Maybe it does login successfully but breaks on a redirect response? (I don't even know if `URL` is capable of doing that, but still...) Maybe you've enabled/disabled IPv6 somewhere?

Comment: Also using old school tcpdump helps as well!  Anything you can use to see packets going over the wire is invaluable for a network programmer

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that. For reference, it also has a Windows port, *windump*.

Answer (score 1):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.java; javac test.java; java test
import java.net.*;
public class test {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  URL register = new URL(
   "http://secure.exoterragame.com/noxastra/login.php" + 
    "?username=" + "guest" + 
    "&password=" + "guest");
  URLConnection conn = register.openConnection();
 }
}
```

Doesn't throw an exception for me. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/users/800237/adithya-surampudi 's suggestion will work.